# How cheap could a .NETMF board be w/Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, .net-micro-framework

I'm getting started with .NETMF and was wondering, what is the cheapest .NETMF board could be developed for, assuming it only has an ethernet jack and lwIP stack for TCP & UDP support? The code running on the board would be pretty small, just serving a small static website over tcp.

Is it possible to make it under $5? $10?

Comment: Netduino+ is about $60 retail single unit. Get the list of chips on the schematic that you need and look it up.

Comment: @kenny isn't netduino+ designed to be more scalable than netduino, which itself is $30. Plus they both use ARM7 processor, which might be overkill for what I want to do, unless thats the min. required by .NETMF?

Comment: If you want to know how to go about finding out the price to make something, that would be fine, but as it is now you are presenting us with a very narrow situation that would be unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: @tunafish24 I don't know what the requirement is, but I'm pretty sure that .NETMF has pretty heavy requirements 32bit processor, ++. The + adds ethernet as you require. Either way it's pretty easy to look up prices for the schematic. I think you'll find that you can find .NETMF-capable ARM processors under $10.

Comment: @tunafish24 why so fixated on .NET MF? If you want to do general embedded programming as your other question implied, then I'd strongly suggest MSP430 or Arduino over .NET MF.

Comment: I don't know what a ".NETMF" is, or a "lwIP stack".  However, for low cost and small internet connectivity I like the PIC 18F67J60.  Given a 3.3V power supply, all you need is a crystal, a few caps, the ethernet transformer, and the RJ45 jack.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm a fan of that for low cost Ethernet too. One question, do you actually need the crystal? Is there a PIC with an internal oscillator and the Ethernet engine?

Comment: @OlinLathrop how easy is it do socket && ssl programming using the PIC microcontroller?

Comment: @darron I'm not fixated on .NETMF. I just don't want to jump into arduino/embedded scene without getting an idea of what's it like. As I mentioned in my earlier reply, I really like the fact that I'd be able to set breakpoints and debug code on the controller plus many other features the platform offers. Once I get the hang of it, then I'll look at arduino.

Comment: @tunafish24 You can set breakpoints and debug on the MSP430, and I'd be very surprised if you couldn't with Arduino too. In fact, that's a generally available feature of most microcontrollers.

Comment: @tunafish24 I'd skip the PIC, personally. I know they're Olin's favorite, but IMHO the tools just aren't as good for the beginner. MSP430 has a great development environment and a free C compiler (and you can start for under $5). With PICs you have to buy a compiler or figure out how to hack in a third party one. Maybe I missed something major, but it seemed like a major pain to me. It looks like there's a new environment for PIC on the way, so maybe they'll fix some of that...

Comment: @kenny: Yes, you need the crystal.  The clock accuracy ethernet requires exceeds what internal R-C oscillators can do on microcontrollers I am aware of.

Comment: @tunafish: I have no idea what you mean by "ssl" programming.

Comment: @darron: The MSP430 is a nice microcontroller line too, but let's not jump there for the wrong reasons.  The Microchip MPLAB IDE is free, works well, and comes with assembler, librarian, and linker.  No, you don't have to buy a compiler.  First, you don't need to use a high level language at all.  My network stack for the 18F is written in assembler, for example.  Second, I think all the compilers have free versions that only have some of the optimizations turned off.  That's plenty fine for hobbyists.

Comment: @Olin: While it's true that the IDE is free, there's a HUGE difference between a free platform with an assembler and a free platform with a C compiler. tunafish24 is starting from a position of wanting to use .NET MF, I think it's extremely likely that he's going to prefer a C compiler to assembler. However, I did some checking and it appears there is a free C compiler from Microchip (and one for HiTech as well), but code optimizations are unavailable as you say. For major microcontroller platforms a C compiler should be taken for granted at this point.

Comment: @Olin: I'm not sure how I missed the Lite Hitech compiler for PIC12... I recently did a PIC12 project and really hated it. Mainly, my problem was the config bit syntax being different between device families, and a real lack of explaination on how to use the config bits for the PIC12. Then, The PICKit3 pod had to be switched from programming to debug modes, and did not seem to function properly in debug mode for me. Last, I was very annoyed (although it was my fault) that the part needed a higher voltage for programming, and I did not happen to see that 'note' when I originally did the board.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I like the low-cost of PIC and even though I'm good in assembly (x86), I just think readability, maintenance and writability of assembly is horrible. Agreed, that one could spend time and make sure the code is very fast and readable, but I just don't like working with it - unless absolutely necessary i.e. MMX, SSE etc. I think it all comes down to preference :)

Comment: @OlinLathrop SSL is basically HTTPS. It's used for sending pages securely. Even though a small chip might be able to handle basic HTTP, HTTPS requires more processing power, because of symmetric & asymmetric encryptions algorithms involved.

Comment: @darron It appears that GHI electronics' update to .NETMF (called RLP_ allows one to use native/C-code in projects as well. So I've pretty much made up my mind to start with NETduino+ or FEZ Ultimate Kit, get a feel of working with ethernet, LCDs, sensors, LEDs etc and then move to Arduino - for max performance & low-cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's important to understand is that the .NET MicroFramework is a memory-managed run-time environment. To simplify the explanation, it is basically a program that implements a *virtual machine*.  The benefit of this is that the code that *you* write at the application level runs on this virtual machine and gets to use all kinds of dynamic objects that can grow and shrink in size and disappear when you don't use them anymore - and all this happens nicely behind the scenes.

[image: .NET MF stack]

This diagram represents all the components required to make this happen. The C# code that you write is at the application level and is "Managed" which runs in the "virtual machine".  Everything below that is "Native" - which runs on the actual hardware.  At some point someone had to port the framework onto a particular piece of hardware for you - this is done at the HAL (Hardware abstraction layer) which they had to write.

So as you can see, all these components can add up to a very large code size (Flash), a lot of RAM at run-time, and a *lot* more CPU cycles than it would take to run a natively compiled C program.

This is why .NET MF devices require a lot of resources and why an ARM7 is actually *not* overkill if you want decent performance and enough room for your C# application.

Here is a [netduino forum post](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/1919-net-micro-framework-minimun-requirements/) talking a bit more about this.

To answer your question of what might be the cheapest way to get a .NET MF board with ethernet, it would probably be to copy the netduino+ design, except with only the components you need and to use their .NET MF port - which they've put a lot of effort in to but [have made accessible from what I understand](http://netduino.com/downloads/).

Comment: Thanks! Excellent answer, just what I wanted to know. Since .NETMF is open-source now, I guess custimizing it/trimming down is the best way to reduce size/cost on this platform.

Comment: @tunafish24, yes, in fact, this is exactly what the makers of the netduino have done.  They left certain things out of their port in order to conserve resources.  IMO .NET MF isn't exactly cost effective, just nice for rapid prototyping.

Answer (score 4):

Setting aside the .NETMF for a second, you are essentially asking for a single board computer with Ethernet. Cost is directly related to the number of units you plan to produce. Cellphones are so cheap because they are made in the millions. If you only make one or two of something it can be orders of magnitude more expensive.

As was pointed out in the comments, the Netduino plus at $60 retail quantity one is certainly an upper bound on cost.

The [Rasberry PI](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) at $35 retail (model with Ethernet), while not supporting .NETMF, does have an ARM processor with sufficient memory so in theory at least one could port the .NETMF to this device.

As to 5-10 dollars, that is extremely ambitious, you would need extremely high volumes. Of course remember [Moore's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) (costs drop in half roughly every 18 months) so if you wait long enough you may see a $10 board running the .NETMF.

Comment: By the time the $60 Netduino+ has dropped to $10 (about three years, with the added bonus of inflation + interest on the $10), the .NETMF will be a 6 GB image that requires a 4.8 GHz 64-core processor!

Comment: @KevinVermeer,  Its about 2 years later. And your prediction was incorrect :) Unfortunately, even on the price, because its stuck at the same price.

Comment: @ppumkin While we are a long way from $10, there is the TI TM4C1294 Connected Launchpad (EK-TM4C1294XL) with Ethernet at $19 delivered. One would need to port the .NET MF to this ARM board, which should be possible in theory.

Comment: Ahh, wow. Very nice specs compared to the latest Netduino Plus 2! How would one go porting to this. The firmware needs to be ported, correct? I have worked with CC2533 firmware, not very pleasant if you don't know 8086 :(

Comment: http://www.mountaineer.org/netmf-for-stm32/  - Somebody already did it, for a measly 25k a year support contract :) But its possible :)