# Program a PIC16F877A using VB.NET

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming, netduino

I have bought a [PIC16F877A microcontroller and its board](http://ram-e-shop.com/oscmax/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=1399) before and since then,  I haven't used it much because I don't really have enough time and patience to learn C. I was thinking to buy a [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) since it can be programmed using VB.NET (which obviously I'm familiar with). However, I  didn't want to abandon the stuff I bought earlier, so therefore I'm asking if there is a way to program the PIC16F877A using VB.NET, maybe using the SDK provided in the Netduino website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 368 bytes of RAM means that there can never be a VB.NET VM on the PIC16F877A, but let's see if we can get a more detailed answer

Comment: @KevinVermeer I mean, is there a way to program it on VB.NET and maybe a converter converts it to C? Or maybe the same syntax as VB.NET?

Comment: I have heard about Pigmeo but don't know much about it, might it be a solution?

Comment: @KevinVermeer, perhaps the answer here could be educational: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/how-cheap-could-a-netmf-board-be-w-ethernet/26429#26429

Comment: @SeifShawkat, Pigmeo looks interesting, not much on their wiki about its limitations though.  Let us know how it turns out for you...

Comment: @JonL Sadly, it only has 2 DLLs: PIC16F9.dll and PIC16F716.dll. Do you think that I can use one of them that will work for the PIC I have (PIC16F877A)?

Comment: @JonL - Yes, that's an excellent answer!  Feel free to copy it over and adjust it so that it's applicable here.

Comment: @SeifShawkat, I have no idea. I know nothing about it other than what I've quickly read from the link you provided.

Comment: If the idea is just to be able to program the PIC in VB.NET, not really to get all the power and functionalitity that VB.NET offers, then how about just using BASIC to program it? If the benefit of VB.NET is needed, then a better microcontroller should just be used instead.

Comment: @TiOLUWA I want to program the PIC16F877A using the Visual basic IDE (If I can just write the code in VB.net syntax in the IDE then save that then have it converted to asse,b;y or somthing that would be great). I found about the Pigmeo project, contacted its owner and he replied saying that there haven't been much development on it lately because he is the only developer and even told me that anyone can join developing. Problem is, I don't know any assembly nor C#. I really want the Pigmeo project to continue, so if you can, try to help developing it. http://dev.pigmeo.org/wiki/Getting_started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  However, you can get a BASIC compiler for your PIC16F877A from Micro Engineering Labs.  I've used some PIC products built with that.

See http://pbp3.com/download.html -- they have a 15 day free trial, after that you will need to open your wallet.

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score -1):

You can read following link for vb tutorial of Serial port
You can have a simple demo here to send data from vb to serial port..later on you can use 8051 or pic microcontroller board to decode it on hardware for leds. 
http://embeddedtweaks.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/accessing-pc-serial-port-in-visual-basic/

Comment: This does not answer the question which was about programming the microcontroller with VB.NET, not the PC.